# Template error using apitome gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-api-documentation, apitome

I am using [rspec_api_documentation](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation) and [apitome](https://github.com/jejacks0n/apitome) to generate api documentation. When I view the `apitome` output in the browser, there is a link entitled 'Simulated Response'. When I click on this, I get the following error:

```
Missing template apitome/docs/simulate
```

What does 'Simulated Response' do, and how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/jejacks0n/apitome/issues/82) the rubygem is several years out of date, so use a more recent release e.g.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'apitome', git: 'https://github.com/jejacks0n/apitome.git', ref: '8fbf5aa'
```

The Simulated response appears to reveal an unformatted response body.